# Add multiple rows to Google Spreadsheet via API

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I can add a new row to a Google spreadsheet with this code:

```
$valueRange = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange();
$valueRange->setValues(["values" => ['data1', 'data2']]);
$range = 'Sheet1!A1:A';
$conf = ["valueInputOption" => "USER_ENTERED"];
$service->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheetId, $range, $valueRange, $conf);
```

How should I change the setValues params to add multiple rows?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

In the meantime I use this approach:

```
$range_number = 1; // Keep spreadsheet header
$data = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
    $range_number++;
    $range = 'Sheet1!A'.$range_number.':XX';
    $values = array( array($data1[$i], $data2[$i], $data3[$i]) );
    $data[] = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(
        array( 'range' => $range, 'values' => $values )
    );
}
$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateValuesRequest(array(
  'valueInputOption' => "USER_ENTERED",
  'data' => $data
));
$result = $service->spreadsheets_values->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $body);

// Clear rest of spreadsheet
$range_number++;
$range = 'Sheet1!A'.$range_number.':XX';
$clearRange = new Google_Service_Sheets_ClearValuesRequest();
$service->spreadsheets_values->clear($spreadsheetId, $range, $clearRange);
```

But this way I have to send the previous data as well. My goal would be just to append the new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to follow the [Insert an empty row or column](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn#insert_an_empty_row_or_column) guide. Indicate "ROWS" as your "dimension" and add how many rows you want by using startIndex and endIndex.

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId:batchUpdate

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "insertDimension": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "dimension": "ROWS",
          "startIndex": 0,
          "endIndex": 100
        },
        "inheritBefore": false
      }
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can add multiple rows by batchUpdate, but with this method I have to set the rows I want to add data. Is there a way to append multiple rows, even if I don't know which row has the last data?

Comment: Have you tried [spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)? as of now this is the append-related methond in SheetsV4.

Comment: Yes. But I can't add more then one row with [append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)

Comment: If you check the sample on this [Append Values guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing#append_values) it demonstrates adding more than one row using that method.

Comment: Thanks, it's working :)
I needed to add the `majorDimension` attribute.

Answer (score 4):

For those of you who want to **append** multiple rows instead of update rows. You can use this solution.

```
$valueRange = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange();

$valueRange->setValues([['John', 'Doe'],['Jane', 'Doe']]);

$range = 'Sheet1!A1:A';
$conf = ["valueInputOption" => "USER_ENTERED"];
$service->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheetId, $range, $valueRange, $conf);
```

It took me ages to work this out hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need an array like this in php, for example

```
[
['value1','value2','value3'],
['value4','value5','value6']
]
```

To do so, if you have multiple array like

```
[
[0][0]=>'value1',[1]=>'value2',[2]=>'value3',
[1][0]=>'value4',[1]=>'value5',[2]=>'value6'
]
```

You need to iterate subArrays

```
$values = [];
$i = 0;
foreach ($yourArr as $subArray):

    foreach ($subArray as $key => $value):

        $values[$i][$key] = $value;

    endforeach;
    $i++;
endforeach;
```

And then

```
$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
    'values' => $values 
]);
```