# Looking to make a Google Sheet recognize multiple new rows of data and send to API in XML format

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'm already familiar with the fact that I can set triggers so that when some data is changed in the sheet, it triggers the function as well as the fact that I can get the last row of the sheet when changed.

The goal of this is to be able to paste multiple new rows into the google sheet, have it recognize these multiple new rows, and send to an external API that only accepts and XML format.

The documentation for the external API to receive this information is here...

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("first_name", "lastRow[1]");
form.append("last_name", "lastRow[2]");
form.append("status", "Cold");
form.append("city", "lastRow[8]");
form.append("state", "lastRow[9]");
form.append("zip_code", "lastRow[10]");
form.append("email_address", "lastRow[0]");
form.append("phone_home ", "lastRow[3]");
form.append("home_type", "lastRow[31]");
form.append("num_bath", "lastRow[41]");
form.append("num_bed", "lastRow[40]");
form.append("budget", "{{budget}}");
form.append("timeframe_to_purchase", "{{timeframe}}");
form.append("credit_estimate", "{{credit score}}");
form.append("client_id", "CM");
form.append("comments", "{{notes}}");

var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://elnpost.net/d.ashx?ckm_campaign_id=42&ckm_key=jkdX9gZD6o",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "29f328bc-ae8d-4107-919c-b524954c8e11"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "contentType": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "data": form
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

The hardest part about this is getting Google Sheets to recognize multiple rows of new data. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42751757/add-multiple-rows-to-google-spreadsheet-via-api).  It's for PHP, but the API should be the same.

Comment: What is the data you want to insert in the Sheets? You want to send the sheet after edited as a XML to the external API?

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the data. I presume you can figure out how to use it.  If you want the dialog to view the data then you will have to create on installable trigger for it.  You may also wish to change the sheet name.  Presently this requires that you paste more than one cell.

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()=='Sheet1' && (e.range.rowEnd-e.range.rowStart)>0 || (e.range.columnEnd-e.range.columnStart)>0) {
    var rg=e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart,e.range.rowEnd-e.range.rowStart+1,e.range.columnEnd-e.range.columnStart+1);
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    var html="<style>td{border:1px solid black)</style><table>";
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
      html+='<tr>';
      for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++) {
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<td>%s</td>', vA[i][j]);
      }
      html+='</tr>';
    }
    html+='</table>';
    var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "View Data");
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, thanks for the prompt answer! I'm very (did I say very?) new to javascript. Most of my thinking is in Python, so I kind of get where you're going with this, but as far as using the answer so that the variables aren't undefined, how would I do this? In the meantime I'll do some research on this myself to figure out what I'm missing. Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, first point is that you can't run this function without an event object (i.e. the `e` parameter.  So just create an onEdit() trigger Menu `Edit/Project Triggers` and connect it onMyEdit(e)...don't forget the `e`.  Then you need to tell it what sheet/tab you want it to work on and then start pasting stuff and watch it work.  I've already tested it.  You don't really need the dialog but it's just a way to see the data that your pasting.  Actually, if you don't want the dialog you can just use a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#getting_started).

Comment: Hi again, just tried to get this to run again, I keep getting this error... TypeError: Cannot call method "getSheet" of undefined. It happened when I was adding singular rows, multiple rows, or deleting singular or multiple rows. Also worth noting... it seems like Google Scripts would only let me make a trigger for 'onMyEdit' not 'onMyEdit(e)'. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The name of the function is all you need for the trigger and that is `onMyEdit` but the parameter e must be in the function declaration `function onMyEdit(e) {` currently I'm guessing that it is not there.